# SSH with a private key without passephrase

Tags: linux, ssh, putty

I have a debian 7 64bits server with my public key inserted into authorized_file.

I can connect to my server with putty without problem.

But when I try to connect to my server with command line on Babun or another terminal with this command :

```
ssh -i /home/mykey.ppk root@myid
```

Terminal ask me passphrase but there isn't...

How can I connect to my server ?

Regards.

Comment: There isn't what exactly?

Comment: I think putty private keys cannot be used directly from a ssh command line. I think putty pageant allows you to convert your current key to ssh format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putty keys are in a different format than OpenSSH keys. To convert them and use for cygwin/linux/cygwin-like shells like badun (which are likely to use OpenSSH), you will need to use **puttygen**:

1. Open PuttyGen
2. Click Load
3. Load your private key
4. Go to Conversions->Export OpenSSH and export your private key

Using the exported key, rather than the ppk will allow you to log in.

Comment: Oh !! I didn't know that! Thank you, it works `ssh -i /mykey.opensshpk root@myhost` !!

Comment: And of course, babun is to use openssh cause I have Oh-my-zsh and putty/kitty doesn't recognize beautiful colors etc...

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure I have this correct, You can use your key with a `putty` client but can't with an `openssh` client?

`openssh` doesn't know what to do with a `.ppk` file (Putty Private Key) so you need to convert it using the program `puttygen`.

You can download it here http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Alternatively, you can just generate another key by running `ssh-keygen`. It will ask you some questions about where to save and if you want to add a password to the key. Then run

```
ssh-copy-id -i /path/to/your_key remote_host_name
```

Then try logging logging on to the remote server by running

```
ssh -i /path/to/your_key remote_host_name
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't have enough reputation to up vote you... With your solution, I have to generate another key and am not able to use existing key.